# VBA Powerpoint - How to highlight selected text

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to highlight the selected text into a colour but this is not working. 
Could you help me with that ?

```
Sub ShadingLtYellow()
    ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.HighlightColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 175)
End Sub
```

Also can I trigger the macro using the a keyboard shortcut such as application onkeys on Excel ?

This would be great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextRange is for backward compatibility with older versions of PowerPoint. With current versions (2010 and later), use the **Textrange2** object instead, it has Highlight:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Font.Highlight.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 175)
```