# How to *un* highlight selected text?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

A previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175015/vba-powerpoint-how-to-highlight-selected-text) described how to use `.Font.Highlight` of `TextRange2` to highlight selected text.

How do I *remove* the highlight?

In particular either of the following...

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Font.Highlight.RGB = 0
```

OR

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Font.Highlight = 0
```

...result in black highlighting instead of no highlighting.

Using `False` or `msoFalse` in place of the zeros has the same effect. There doesn't seem to be a Boolean switch to turn highlighting on or off (as there is in Word) and there is no supporting documentation of any kind to be found.

Comment: Try, please: `... .Highlight.RGB = RGB(225, 225, 225)`. It will color it in white...

Comment: @FaneDuru That's fine but not much use if the textbox isn't filled white

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was a workaround suggestion... In such a case, you have to color it in the textbox background. If you are not sure what RGB color it contains, you firstly have to color it by code and use the same from `Highlight`. I use VBA in Powerpoint very seldom. Try, also `... Highlight = xlNone`. Not tested. Only by assimilation with the ordinary VBA rules... VBA CorelDraw uses something similar.

Comment: `xlNone` should be `-4142`. Try also this constant. Maybe the first try would have a meaning only in Excel...

Comment: Yeh it seems it does: I tried `msoNone`, which sometimes works as a substitute. That numerical value turns the highlight a light blue, sadly :(

Comment: I have the same challenge to solve and none of those suggestions worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint 2019 and 365 it is possible to use Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso method to remove highlighting. See this question:

[Unhighlighting text (and preserve all other font settings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019669/unhighlighting-text-and-preserve-all-other-font-settings?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aleksey Malov.

If the text has the same highlight color as the highlight picker, we only have to run the MSO command only once.
But, if the highlight color of the selected text is not the same color of the current highlight color, we should run the MSO command TWICE.

```
Set tr = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2
'Highlight once
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("TextHighlightColorPickerLicensed")
'Select the textrange again
tr.Select
'finally, unhighlight the textrange
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("TextHighlightColorPickerLicensed")
```

The above snippet fails to un-highlight the text if the highlight color is the same as the picker.
The problem is that we cannot identify the current highlight color on the ribbon.(Maybe there is a way but not simple)

My work-around is just using the shortcut key sequence:

```
 SendKeys "%(htcn)"
```

Alt-'h', 'tc' and 'n'