# Unable to de-highlight on PowerPoint 2019 through VSTO plugin

Tags: vb.net, vsto, office-interop, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Do not have enough reputation to comment on the answer by "Aleksey Malov" to query at [un-highlighting text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019669/unhighlighting-text-and-preserve-all-other-font-settings).

**Preconditions**: PowerPoint 2019 or 365. Presentation must be opened with window.

**Original shape with highlight**:

[image]

I'm opening a new PPT file from the VSTO plugin by saving a copy of original PPT file and then performing the following operations on selected shape object. I'm trying to do this using PowerPoint VSTO plugin with Office 2019. This works for me during debugging through Visual Studio but not through the installed plugin.

```
if(Application.CommandBars.GetEnabledMso("TextHighlightColorPickerLicensed"))
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("TextHighlightColorPickerLicensed")
```

My queries:

1. What does "Presentation must be opened with window." mean?
2. Why does it not work in the installed plugin?
3. If I attach the running PowerPoint process in Visual Studio even with Release config, I get expected result where highlight is removed. Any reasons why?

Comment: >> "What does "Presentation must be opened with window." mean?"

What line does this occur on?  I'm guessing that your code is attempting to select a shape; in order to select anything, PPT requires a visible window. If you're opening the presentation w/o a window, you can't use .Select on shapes/slides.

Comment: I'm not selecting the shape but the text run in shape. Is that also a problem?

VSTO code:

ActPres.SaveCopyAs(newFileName);
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Presentations.Open(newFileName);

foreach (Shape sh in CurSlide.Shapes)
 UnhighlightTextInShape(sh);  ===> as in Aleskey's answer
 
Note: ActPres is the presentation opened by user on launching PowerPoint application. newFileName and CurSlide is what the name suggests.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you're selecting anything, true, but in this case, I suspect that you MUST select the text in question, else the command bar (well, ribbon UI) in question is disabled. Try it manually in PPT; you'll see that unless you select some text, the text highlighting button is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

> What does "Presentation must be opened with window." mean?

In the code you are relying on the `CommandBars` object which may not exist until the window is created. To get the code running correctly a window must be initialized.

> Why does it not work in the installed plugin?

Well, you need to add some logging statements to see why YOUR code fails. Only looking at the log files you may find any difference.

> If I attach the running PowerPoint process in Visual Studio even with Release config, I get expected result where highlight is removed. Any reasons why?

There can be multiple reasons. One of them is that VS could be run with admin privileges which causes all child processes to be run under the same security context. Files may not be accessible without admin privileges and etc.

Comment: The "if" condition used to return true(through VS with Admin) resulting in de-highlighting which is what I want to achieve and false(with installed plugin).

Yes. I was running VS with admin privileges earlier. When I ran VS normally without Admin, I see same behavior as installed plugin which is definitely a setback.

Comment: It seems you have found the cause. The control has a different state depending on the permissions evaluated for the PowerPoint process.